# Filtering by condition in child of object in Django

Tags: python, django

Django 1.11. I have a model `Cat`:

```
class Cat(OrderedModel):
  age = models.IntegerField()
```

and a model `Flea`:

```
class Flea(models.Model):
  dangerous = models.BooleanField()
  cat = models.ForeignKey(Cat)
```

A cat can have many fleas. Cats are an ordered model. Given a position in this order, I want to get the next cat which has at least one non-dangerous flea. My first attempt:

```
def get_next_cat(self, current_pos):
  cat = Cat.objects.filter(order__gt=current_pos).first()
  fleas = Flea.objects.filter(cat=cat, dangerous=False)
  if fleas is None:
    return get_next_cat(current_pos + 1)
  return cat
```

This seems verbose, and I would like to be able to perform this logic in the first statement of the method. I.e. to get the first next cat such as that at least one of that cat's fleas has `false` for its `dangerous` property. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use [lookups that span the relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: And you'll want to annotate each cat with the count of fleas that are dangerous: use a [filter on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)

Comment: @dirkgroten Thanks - the relationship-spanning lookups did the job. If you want to create an answer I'll give it the green tick.

Comment: btw, your test `if fleas is None` can't be right, because `fleas` is always a `QuerySet`, even if it's the empty `QuerySet`, it will never be `None`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to go at it, but since you just need to exclude cats that have at least one dangerous flea, you can use [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). For example:

```
Cat.objects.filter(flea__dangerous=True)
```

will give you the cats that have at least one dangerous flea.

You could also annotate each cat with a count of fleas that are dangerous, using a [filter on annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations), if you're on Django 2.x. But that might be over-complicating things in your case.

Comment: Thanks. To answer my question directly, I used: `Cat.objects.filter(order__gt=current_pos, flea__dangerous=False).first()`

Comment: That's not the correct query, because it gives you the first cat that has at least one non-dangerous flea (but could still also have dangerous fleas), rather than cats that have *no* dangerous flea. Try using `exclude` instead.

Comment: You're right, my question was falsely formulated. I'll edit my question, since this is the behaviour I want.